# Flash drawing line overlapping check

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have an application where user have to draw a line on the canvas without overlapping it. Is there a way to test the overlapping? I have googled already but found result with circles and rectangle overlapping. My case is different. Here user will draw lines on canvas without overlap the line itself. May be I am missing something so any guidance is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I take it you mean the user draws a line with some sort of pen tool, using the mouse.

Here's what I would do:

First, hold the path of the line drawn in a BitmapData object.

```
var lineBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(display.width,display.height,true,0x00000000);
```

This creates a transparent bitmap object with the user's line on it.

On each frame (or timer event, if you use timer) do the following:

1.capture the current mouse position and put it into a Point object.

```
var currentMousePosition:Point = new Point(mouse.x,mouse.y);
```

you will also need a point representing the upper-left corner of your bitmapData.

```
var pt1:Point = new Point(1,1);
```

2.perform collision detection between the current mouse position and the lineBitmapData

```
var result:Boolean = lineBitmapData.hitTest(pt1, 0xFF, currentMousePosition);
```

the second parameter in the hitTest method is the threshhold value. Basically, this needs to be set to the minimum alpha value that you want to count as a hit.

3.check the result of the hitTest. If it's false, this means what the user is about to draw this frame does not intersect what was already drawn. In this case, you add the bit that was drawn during the last frame to the lineBitmapData.

If the hitTest returns true, however, that means the user is about to make his line intersect, so your program needs to stop the drawing (or whatever behavior you want).

```
    if(result){
 myPenTool.stopDrawing();}else{
var drawnLastFrame:BitmapData = myPenTool.drawSingleFrameLine();
lineBitmapData.draw(drawnLastFrame);}
```

4.Update what the user sees on the screen with the new lineBitmapData

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried that but doesn't work very well. It only work if I draw very slowly so it captured all the mouse position but if I draw faster it bypass all the checks, I think need to get all the points of the path can solve this but not sure how to do that. Thank you anyway